# How to join Date and Time of variable length using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a fixed-length `Time` list:

```
time_list = ['21:00:00', '22:00:00', '23:00:00', '00:00:00', '01:00:00']
```

However, I have a long `Date` list:

```
date_list = 
['2019-07-09',
 '2019-07-09',
 '2019-07-09',
 '2019-07-09',
 '2019-07-09',
 '2019-07-09',
 '2019-07-09',
 '2019-07-10',
 '2019-07-10',
 '2019-07-10',
 '2019-07-10',
 '2019-07-08',
 '2019-07-08',
 '2019-07-08'
 ....
 ]
```

What I want to do is `join` `date_list` and `time_list` so the new `df` looks like this:

```
date_time =
['2019-07-09 21:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 22:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 23:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 00:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 01:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 21:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 22:00:00',
 '2019-07-10 23:00:00',
 '2019-07-10 00:00:00',
 '2019-07-10 01:00:00',
 '2019-07-10 21:00:00',
 '2019-07-08 22:00:00',
 '2019-07-08 23:00:00',
 '2019-07-08 00:00:00'
 ....
 ]
```

As you can see that the `time_list` is applied to `date_list` similar to one to one mapping. When the `time_list` runs out of value, it is repeated again but `date_list` is the same length and won't repeat.

**What did I do?**

I tried to do:

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([date_list, time_list]).map(' '.join).tolist()
```

But it does for each `date_list` joins `time_list` which gives extra values.

I also tried to do this but wont work:

```
[date_list  + " " + time_list]
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
n=1+len(date_list)//len(time_list)
[x + ' ' +y for x , y in zip(date_list,(time_list*n)[:len(date_list)])]
```

Or we using the `itertools.cycle`

```
import itertools
[x+' '+y for x,y in zip(date_list, itertools.cycle(time_list))]
```

Answer (score 1):

On a very intuitive level I would simply have 2 for loops and a 'cyclical numerator' such that:

```
from collections import Counter

date_dict = Counter(date_list)
date_time = []
cyclical = 0

for d in date_dict:
    index = 0
    n = date_dict[d]
    for _ in range(n): 
        t = time_list[cyclical%len(time_list)]  
        cycle += 1
        date_time.append(d+" "+t)
```

desired result:

```
['2019-07-09 21:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 22:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 23:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 00:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 01:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 21:00:00',
 '2019-07-09 22:00:00',
 '2019-07-10 23:00:00',
 '2019-07-10 00:00:00',
 '2019-07-10 01:00:00',
 '2019-07-10 21:00:00',
 '2019-07-08 22:00:00',
 '2019-07-08 23:00:00',
 '2019-07-08 00:00:00']
```